# Where did the expression "have at it" come from?

Tags: etymology

Couldn't find its etymology...  anyone knows?
What does its meaning break down to?
Also, when should it be used best?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't recognise this as an expression.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In modern usage, to *have at* is to *attempt*, to *go ahead*, or to *attack physically*. I suspect it comes from a shortening of the phrase *have a go (at)*, which is used in the very same situations. *Have at it* means *try (to do) it*, *have at thee!* announces an attack in Shakespearian English, and *he had at her with a knife* means he attacked her with it.

Comment: The situation I think of in conjunction with this phrase is someone who tries to do something, say unscrew the lid of a jar of some kind, with all of their might and fails. Another person steps up and says, "can I try it?", to which the reply is "Sure, have at it." The connotation being that the speaker thinks it's impossible to succeed, but still gives their permission to try.

Comment: @Wayne: Yeah, it does have that sort of cynicism to it.

Comment: I agree.  It seems to also flip again if used with "we/us", i.e. ok's here *our* tasks, lets have at it shall *we*?

Answer (score 3):

[Straitdope's forum](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=97979) suggests

> The phrase "have at avail" means to have at an advantage and the earliest citation is to Malory (Le Morte D'Arthur) in the phrase* "Him thought no worship to have a knight at such avail, . . ."

Apparently "have at you" (or similar) appears in several Shakespeare plays in the sense of: let battle commence.

Comment: Just for the record: "Have at you now!" — *Hamlet* ◆ "Have at you with a proverb [...] Have at you with another;" — *Comedy of Errors* ◆ "Have at you!" — *Henry VIII* ◆ "Have at you, then, affection's men at arms." — *Love's Labour's Lost* ◆ "Then have at you with my wit!" — *Romeo and Juliet* ◆ "since you have begun, / Have at you for a bitter jest or two." — *Taming of the Shrew* ◆ "Come, both you cogging Greeks; have at you both!" — *Troilus and Cressida*.

Answer (score 0):

The OED dates "have at" to the 14th century:

> **V 27 b.** intransitive. ***With at.*** **To go at, esp. aggressively or forcefully; to tackle or attack; (also) to make an attempt at, ‘have a go at’. In early use chiefly in imperative, frequently with first-person meaning: ‘let me at (you, it, etc.)’, ‘here goes’ (now archaic).** Formerly also with other prepositions (and adverbs), as †after, †among.
>
> c1400  (▸?c1390)    Sir Gawain & Green Knight (1940) l. 2288   *‘Haf at þe þenne,’ quoþ þat oþer.* [trans "Have at thee then," said the other one.]
>
> 1639   T. Fuller Hist. Holy Warre iii. xi. 128   *He wintered in Askelon, intending next spring to have at Jerusalem.*
>
> 1916   J. Galsworthy Sheaf 298   *One would not admit a physical defeat, but clench the teeth and have at it again.*
>
> 2009   New Yorker 2 Feb. 50/3   *After the tabloids and the upstate papers had at her, she attended another friend's birthday party.*

> What does its meaning break down to?

The "at" was probably

OED

> 3. **At a person** (Latin apud):
>
> **†a. In personal contact with; in the immediate presence or company of. Obsolete (repl. by with, by, beside, in presence of, before).**
>
> c1275  (▸?a1200)    Laȝamon Brut (Calig.) (1978) l. 12621   *We woren..at [c1300 Otho mid] Arðure þan kinge.* [We were with Arthur the king.]

The idea could be that the threated blow, etc., would be in contact with the person threatened.

> Also, when should it be used best?

Some time prior to 1900. It is now archaic.

NB, **have at** is not a shortening of "have a go at", which is a much later (late 18th c.) construction.

> **P1.** Chiefly colloquial. **to have a go.**
>
> **a.(a)** Chiefly with at. **To aim a blow or shot at someone or something; to make an attack or onslaught upon someone or something.**
>
> 1792   Lady's Mag. May 244/1   *I felt such a flow of spirits and courage, that I hid myself behind a tree, determined to have a go at him—the moment he passed me, I fired my pistol.*