# "Have at it" : what's the object of the transitive verb "have" here?

Tags: transitive-verbs

I intuitively understand the meaning of the phrase "have at it!", but I can't explain it to myself. I understand that "to have" in this sense requires an object to be valid, so why is it missing here yet it doesn't sound as weird as other objectless *to have*, such as "The president has in the office"?

Comment: A better expression is "have a GO at it" (British). "Have at it" is a clumsy abbreviation.

Comment: Not only related, but helpful: [Where did the expression "have at it" come from?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/7173/10041)

Answer (score 5):

I believe that your analysis is mistaken: *to have* in this expression is intransitive.

Of course the verb *have* is normally transitive, which is why you assume that it must be transitive here. But I would argue that the *to have at* is a phrasal verb, whose object is syntactically the object of the preposition *at*. This is similar to a multitude of other phrasal verbs, such as *to look at*.

So *to have* in this idiom is intransitive, and the notional object is expressed as the object of the prepositional complement *at*.